# Creating a responsive menu using media queries : Menu doesn't scale

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make my menu work in different resolutions using media queries but stuck in somewhere. Between 1025 and 1441 (or higher) pixels, font size must be changed accordingly with the screen but it doesn't. Instead, I see this when I reduce the browser size.

http://i.imgur.com/KasiLZw.png (I know most of you don't like images, but I added it just in case)

Here's my code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPVzaW

HTML

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='/book/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>Page details</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='/details/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>Book details</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='/comments/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>Comments</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='/suggestions/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>Suggestions</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='/lists/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>Lists</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='/inculture/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>In culture</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='/cover-images/<?php echo $url; ?>'><span>Cover images</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cssmenu {
    width: 55%;
}

#cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #6A5546;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353535;
    zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#cssmenu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

#cssmenu li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #b4aaa2;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px 7px 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

#cssmenu li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;
}

#cssmenu li.active a {
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1441px) {
    #cssmenu {
        width: 57%;
    }

    #cssmenu ul {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #6A5546;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #353535;
        zoom: 1;
    }

    #cssmenu ul li a {
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried switching media screen to media all? i heard sometimes the screen one does not work on all devices.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to using wrong css selector to specify font size.

UL and OL behave somehow special because I think by default the font size is used from the LI element and not from the UL.

So if you specify it on UL but by default there is a size on LI, it won't make any change. You should specify on LI.

As this:

```
#cssmenu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1441px) {
    #cssmenu ul li {
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}
```